# Is it Undefined Behavior to have a non-POD struct inherit from a POD struct in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I am using a C-compatible library that declares

```
typedef struct _gsk_oid {
    int                 count;
    gsk_uint32 *        elements;
} gsk_oid;
```

I can't change the library. In my C++ though I want an OID struct that I can use as a gsk_oid but that also has a constructor so I can create an OID in code. So I have

```
struct oidX : public gsk_oid
{
    oidX(int countX, gsk_uint32 first, ...);
    oidX(const gsk_oid *inOID);
    ~oidX();
};
```

That way I can code, for example, `oidX testOID1(9, 1,  3,   6,  1,  5,  5,  7, 48,  1);` and then use testOID1 in context that expects a gsk_oid.

Is this going to lead to undefined behavior? I am seeing strange results that I cannot explain and I am wondering if the above is an invitation to problems.

Comment: How are you using this? What are those strange results?

Comment: What does "bad idea" mean? This seems to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: What std::is_pod says about your structs?

Comment: From the cpp-core-guidelines: [Prefer concrete types over class heiraches](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c10-prefer-concrete-types-over-class-hierarchies)

Comment: Such inheritance is not in itself a problem. To the extent there is a problem, it lies somewhere in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel The strange results are that I am calling a method that expects a gsk_oid* as a parameter. My debug code shows the expected values in the oidX but debugging code in the called method shows incorrect values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik by "bad idea" I mean is doing this an invitation to problems.

Comment: Pretty much anything that one might do in C++ can result in problems of some kind. There's nothing inherently wrong with this kind of inheritance. It is well-formed. To the extent to whatever problems you're seeing, it cannot be due solely to this kind of inheritance, but due to some other factor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that is the sort of answer I am looking for. I don't want you all to debug my program; I just wondered if inheriting a non-POD from a POD and passing that by address to a method that expects the POD was inherently a problematic thing.

Comment: For the future: the question you really want to ask, next time, is whether something is "undefined behavior". A "bad idea" might still be a bad idea, in a general sense, but it won't be undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior" has a well-established meaning. A "bad idea" is a purely subjective term, which is generally frowned upon, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik fair enough. I edited the question.

Comment: Using `...` like you do is a legacy "C" construct (va_args) with all kinds of (safety and typesafety) issues. Consider rewriting your code to a variadic template function/constructor e.g. `template<typename... ags_t>  oidX(int countX, gsk_uint32 first, args_t&&...)`.

Comment: you may be better off wrapping it in a class instead then have a method access the struct or struct members - since the base class has now virtual destructor. depends on your use case though.

Comment: Thanks all. I got it working. Problem turns out not to have had anything to do with POD inheritance -- just your basic program bug. It was a tough debug, and I was trying to eliminate POD inheritance as a cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There's really not much more to add.   There isn't something to point to to say that it's not legal.

Also, if it were a problem it would be trivial for your compiler to warn you you're doing something dumb - and they don't.

Also, if this were illegal, it's unlikely that it would be undefined behavior.   It would be defined illegal as it's not something that is a halting-problem-type-of-thing type of thing.   You can just know it's happening and disallow it if it's not a valid program.